# how to unit test an android module

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, module

I have an android library module that I would like to add unit tests to.
do I need to have the module in a project to be able to run the tests?
is there a way to test the module independently from a project?

Answer (score 1):

To use JUnit tests for your Android application, you need to add it as dependency to your Gradle build file.

```
dependencies {
// Unit testing dependencies
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
// Set this dependency if you want to use the Hamcrest matcher library
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
// more stuff, e.g., Mockito
}
```

You can also instruct the Gradle build system to return default values for method calls in the `android.jar`with the following configuration in your Gradle build file.

```
android {
// ...
testOptions {
unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
}


 In your app/src/test directory create the following two test methods for the ConverterUtil class.

 package com.vogella.android.temperature.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
 import org.junit.Before;
 import org.junit.Test;

 import com.vogella.android.temperature.ConverterUtil;

 public class ConverterUtilTest {

 @Test
 public void testConvertFahrenheitToCelsius() {
    float actual = ConverterUtil.convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(100);
    // expected value is 212
    float expected = 212;
    // use this method because float is not precise
    assertEquals("Conversion from celsius to fahrenheit failed", expected, actual, 
    0.001);
   }

  @Test
   public void testConvertCelsiusToFahrenheit() {
    float actual = ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheitToCelsius(212);
    // expected value is 100
    float expected = 100;
    // use this method because float is not precise
    assertEquals("Conversion from celsius to fahrenheit failed", expected, actual, 
 0.001);
 }

 }
```

Ensure your unit tests are correctly implemented by running test tests. They should run successfully.[refer this link](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html)

Comment: my question was about a library that is designed as a module in android studio. not an actual project. can I run tests on it without adding it in a project.

Comment: Has this been answered? I am looking for something similar.